# How does this code produce "I love you" without any characters or digits?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Taken from - http://www.echojs.com/news/8518

How does this produce `window.alert("I love you");`? I understand how it can obtain `I` from `Infinity`, that's about it

```
    $= ~[];    $={___:
   ++$,$$$$: (![]+"")[$],
    __$:++$,$_$_:(![]+"")
      [$],_$_:++$,$_$$:
        ({} + "")[$],
           $$_$
             :


       ($[$]+"")   [$],_$$:
     ++$,$$$_:(!""+"")[$],$__:
      ++$,$_$:++$,$$__:({}+"")     
       [$],$$_: ++$,$$$:++$,
         $___:++$,$__$:++$
          };$.$_ = ($.$_=
             $ + "")
                [


             $.$_$]+      ($._$=
            $.$_[$.__$  ])+($.$$=(
           $.$+"")[$.__$])+((!$)+"")
           [$._$$]+($.__=$.$_[$.$$_
            ])+($.$=(!""+"")[$.__$
              ]) + ($._= (!""+"")                  
               [ $._$_]) +$.$_
                  [ $.$_$ ]+
                    $.__+


            $._$+    $.$;
          $.$$=$.$+(!""+"")
        [$._$$]+$.__+$._+$.$+
        $.$$;$.$=($.___)[$.$_]
         [$.$_];$.$($.$($.$$+
           "\""+$.$_$_+(![]+
             "")[$._$_]+
                $.$$$_+
                 "\\"+


        $.__$+    $.$$_+
      $._$_+$.__+"(\\\"\\"+
     $.__$+$.__$+$.__$+"\\"+
   $.$__+$.___+(![]+"")[$._$_]+
   $._$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$_+
    $.$$$_+"\\"+$.$__+  $.___+
      "\\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$.__$+
        $._$+$._+".\\\"\\"+
          $.$__  +$.___+
            ")"+ "\"")
              ( ))(
                );
```

http://jsbin.com/OhisIQAW/1/edit

Comment: Downvote is not mine, but this looks off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may have better luck on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It seems very much about programming to me. There must be some string concatenation and variable handling in there somewhere. I see what appears to be an array definition at the beginning, but there's no instance of the letter `v`, for example.

Comment: I've moved it to Puzzles & Code Golf - http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20790/how-does-this-code-produce-i-love-you-without-any-characters-or-digits

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Puzzles & Code Golf have recommended me to ask it on StackOverflow... what now?

Comment: @rickyduck, that's unfortunate, I stand corrected. I thought Code Golf was also about reading code, not just writing it. Voting to reopen this, then, my apologies.

Comment: @plalx Thanks for the explanation, but I still don't see how specific characters are declared.

Comment: @plalx - I'm with you. I got the -1, and I got the NaN, but I can't get down to `v`, or any other character for that matter

Comment: @rickyduck I just posted an answer with more explanations.

Comment: @rickyduck Forget about the NaN, I just forgot to evaluate the first expression before the rest when I posted my comment ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have translated the whole code:

```
$ = ~[];                
/*
 * $ = -1
 */

$ = {
    ___:++$,              // $.___  = $ = 0
    $$$$: (![] + "")[$],  // $.$$$$ = "false"[0]           = "f" unuse
    __$: ++$,             // $.__   = $ = 1
    $_$_: (![] + "")[$],  // $.$_$_ = "false"[1]           = "a"
    _$_: ++$,             // $._$_  = $ = 2
    $_$$: ({} + "")[$],   // $.$_$$ = "[object Object]"[2] = "b" unuse
    $$_$:($[$] + "")[$],  // $.$$_$ = "undefined"[2]       = "d" unuse
    _$$:++$,              // $._$$  = $ = 3
    $$$_: (!"" + "")[$],  // $.$$$_ = "true"[3]            = "e"
    $__:++$,              // $.$__  = $ = 4
    $_$: ++$,             // $.$_$  = $ = 5
    $$__: ({} + "")[$],   // $.$$__ = "[object Object]"[5] = "c" unuse
    $$_: ++$,             // $.$$_  = $ = 6
    $$$: ++$,             // $.$$$  = $ = 7
    $___: ++$,            // $.$___ = $ = 8
    $__$: ++$             // $.$__$ = $ = 9
};
/*
 * build digit and data
 */

$.$_ = 
    ($.$_ = $ + "")[$.$_$] +      // $.$_ = "[object Object]"
                                    // "[object Object]"[5]        = "c"
    ($._$ = $.$_[$.__$]) +        // $._$ = "[object Object]"[1] = "o"
    ($.$$ = ($.$ + "")[$.__$]) +  // $.$$ = "undefined"[1]       = "n"
    ((!$) + "")[$._$$] +          // "false"[3]                  = "s"
    ($.__ = $.$_[$.$$_]) +        // $.__ = "[object Object]"[6] = "t"
    ($.$ = (!"" + "")[$.__$]) +   // $.$  = "true"[1]            = "r"
    ($._ = (!"" + "")[$._$_]) +   // $._  = "true"[2]            = "u"
    $.$_[$.$_$] +                 // "[object Object]"[5]        = "c"
    $.__ +                        //                               "t"
    $._$ +                        //                               "o"
    $.$;                          //                               "r"
/*
 * $.$_ = "constructor"
 */

$.$$ = 
    $.$ +                 //             "r"
    (!"" + "")[$._$$] +   // "true"[3] = "e"
    $.__ +                //             "t"
    $._ +                 //             "u"
    $.$ +                 //             "r"
    $.$$;                 //             "n"
/*
 * $.$$ = "return"
 */

$.$ = 
    ($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];  // (0)["constructor"]["constructor"] 
/* 
 * $.$ = function Function(){ [native code] }
 */

$.$(                    // Function(
    $.$(                  //   Function(
        $.$$ +              //     "return
        "\"" +              //     "\""
        $.$_$_ +            //     "a"
        (![] + "")[$._$_] + //     "l"
        $.$$$_ +            //     "e"
        "\\" +              //     "\\"
        $.__$ +             //     "1"
        $.$$_ +             //     "6"
        $._$_ +             //     "2"
        $.__ +              //     "t"
        "(\\\"\\" +         //     "(\\\"\\"
        $.__$ +             //     "1"
        $.__$ +             //     "1"
        $.__$ +             //     "1"
        "\\" +              //     "\\"
        $.$__ +             //     "4"
        $.___ +             //     "0"
        (![] + "")[$._$_] + //     "l"
        $._$ +              //     "o"
        "\\" +              //     "\\"
        $.__$ +             //     "1"
        $.$$_ +             //     "6"
        $.$$_ +             //     "6"
        $.$$$_ +            //     "e"
        "\\" +              //     "\\"
        $.$__ +             //     "4"
        $.___ +             //     "0"
        "\\" +              //     "\\"
        $.__$ +             //     "1"
        $.$$$ +             //     "7"
        $.__$ +             //     "1"
        $._$ +              //     "o"
        $._ +               //     "u"
        ".\\\"\\" +         //     ".\\\"\\""
        $.$__ +             //     "4"
        $.___ +             //     "0"
        ")" +               //     ")"
        "\""                //     "\""
    )()                   //   )()
)();                    // )();
/*
 * Function(
 *   Function(
 *     "return\"ale\\162t(\\\"\\111\\40lo\\166e\\40\\171ou.\\\"\\40)\""
 *   )()
 * )();
 */
```

also you can read it from here: https://gist.github.com/mutoo/9003010

Comment: Best answer as it gives the full explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple to decode actually. Just open up a debugger and and evaluate every statements (in order). To find the statements, look for `;`. It will then give you the result of the expressions and will help you to find out how they affect each other and then you can analyse every expression individually to see how they were constructed.

**Expression #1**

```
$= ~[]; // -1
```

**Expression #2**

```
$={___:
   ++$,$$$$: (![]+"")[$],
    __$:++$,$_$_:(![]+"")
      [$],_$_:++$,$_$$:
        ({} + "")[$],
           $$_$
             :


       ($[$]+"")   [$],_$$:
     ++$,$$$_:(!""+"")[$],$__:
      ++$,$_$:++$,$$__:({}+"")     
       [$],$$_: ++$,$$$:++$,
         $___:++$,$__$:++$
          };
```

[image]

Here we see some letters started to pop up so let's see how? First let's look at the `$$$$` property that references `'f'`.

```
$={___:++$, $$$$: (![]+"")[$],
```

In the above code, we know that `$` was initially `-1` and now we see `++$` which means `$` is now `0`, then we look at `(![]+"")[$]` which defines the value of the `$$$$` property.

```
(![]+"") //evaluates to 'false'
'false'[$] //which we can translate to...
'false'[0]; //f
```

Let's now do the next property `$_$_`, which holds the value `'a'`.

```
__$:++$, $_$_:(![]+"")[$]
```

We can see again that `++$` increments `$` by `1` so we are at `1` now, then it's the same expression as for the letter `f`, but we are at index `1` so:

```
'false'[1]; //a
```

You can use the same approach to find out the rest of the code, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is a cool puzzle. It's not that bad when you break it down, but it does rely on a lot of JavaScript quirks. I've done a few lines to show how variables are getting set to integer and characters. If anyone wants to finish this, I would gladly make it a community wiki.

```
 $ = ~ []; // $ = -1
 $ = {
     ___: ++$,                // ___ = 0, $ = 0
     $$$$: (![] + "")[$],     // $$$$ = "f";
     __$: ++$,                // __$ = 1, $ = 1
     $_$_: (![] + "")[$],     // $_$_ = "a"
     _$_: ++$,                // _$_ = 2, $ = 2
     $_$$: ({} + "")[$],      // $_$$ = "b"
     $$_$: ($[$] + "")[$],    // $$_$ = "d"
     _$$: ++$,                // _$$ = 3, $ = 3
     $$$_: (!"" + "")[$],
     $__: ++$,
     $_$: ++$,
     $$__: ({} + "")[$],
     $$_: ++$,
     $$$: ++$,
     $___: ++$,
     $__$: ++$
 };

 $.$_ = ($.$_ =
 $ + "")[$.$_$] + ($._$ =$.$_[$.__$]) +
 ($.$$ = ($.$ + "")[$.__$]) + ((!$) + "")[$._$$] +
 ($.__ = $.$_[$.$$_]) +
 ($.$ = (!"" + "")[$.__$]) +
 ($._ = (!"" + "")[$._$_]) + $.$_[$.$_$] +
 $.__ + $._$ + $.$;

 $.$$ = $.$ + (!"" + "")[$._$$] + $.__ + $._ + $.$ + $.$$;

 $.$ = ($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];

 $.$($.$($.$$ + "\"" + $.$_$_ + (![] + "")[$._$_] + $.$$$_ +
         "\\" +
         $.__$ + $.$$_ +
         $._$_ + $.__ + "(\\\"\\" +
         $.__$ + $.__$ + $.__$ + "\\" +
         $.$__ + $.___ + (![] + "")[$._$_] +
         $._$ + "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$_ + $.$$_ +
         $.$$$_ + "\\" + $.$__ + $.___ +
         "\\" + $.__$ + $.$$$ + $.__$ +
         $._$ + $._ + ".\\\"\\" +
         $.$__ + $.___ +
         ")" + "\"")
     ())();
```

Comment: I posted the answer 11 minutes ago, but.. yeah =P

Comment: I know, sorry! I was working on mine for 11 minutes, so I didn't see it. I'll upvote yours.